# Why is the Manifest not available in the constructor?

Tags: class, scala, types, constructor, manifest

Consider this code:

```
class Foo[T : Manifest](val id: String = manifest[T].erasure.getName)
```

I basically want to store an identifier in Foo, which is often just the class name.

Subclass which do not need a special identifier could then easily use the default value.

But this doesn't even compile, the error message is:

```
error: No Manifest available for T.
```

Is there another approach which will work?

EDIT:

Why does this work if the manifest isn't available until the primary constructor?

```
class Foo[T: Manifest](val name: String) { 
  def this() = this(manifest[T].erasure.getName)
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but you'll have much cleaner code if you use `manifest[T]` instead of `implicitly[Manifest[T]]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the syntactic sugar is removed from that context bound, it gets rewritten as:

```
class Foo[T]
  (val id: String = implicitly[Manifest[T]].erasure.getName)
  (implicit ev$1: Manifest[T]) = ...
```

So the Manifest evidence simply isn't available when determining the default value of `id`.  I'd instead write something like this:

```
class Foo[T : Manifest](id0: String = "") {
  val id = if (id0 != "") id0 else manifest[T].erasure.getName
}
```

---

In your second approach (which is a great solution, by the way!), expect a rewrite similar to:

```
class Foo[T](val name: String)(implicit x$1: Manifest[T]) { 
  def this()(implicit ev$2: Manifest[T]) = this(manifest[T].erasure.getName)
}
```

So yes, the manifest **is** available before the call to `manifest[T].erasure`

Comment: But doesn't create that a superfluous field?

Comment: To avoid the superfluous field, remove the `val` modifier from the definition of `id0`?

Comment: Kipton - True that, consider it gone

Comment: @soc - It's usually best to avoid underscores, a heavily overloaded symbol, unless the spec demands it.