# Creating a generic actor subclass that also takes a constructor parameter

Tags: scala, akka, scala-2.10

I have the following code, where `T` is a actor subclass that should also take a constructor argument:

```
abstract class AbstractActor(dest: ActorRef) extends Actor {
  //...
}

class ChildActor(dest: ActorRef) extends AbstractActor(dest) {
  //...
}

class ParentActor[T <: AbstractActor : ClassTag] extends Actor {
  val childRef = context.actorOf(Props(classOf[T], destActorRef))
  //...
}
```

The compiler gives the error: "class type required but T found". I assume the problem is that one could also define childActor without the constructor parameter:

```
class ChildActor extends AbstractActor(dest) {
  //...
}
```

So, I tried:

```
class ParentActor[T <: AbstractActor : ClassTag] extends Actor {

  def createT(dest: ActorRef)(implicit ev: Manifest[T]): ActorRef =
    context.actorOf(Props(ev.runtimeClass, dest))

  val childRef = createT(destActorRef)
  //...
}
```

But then I get: "no manifest available for T". Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: For the "no manifest available for T" part, this thread may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7294761/why-is-the-manifest-not-available-in-the-constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first attempt, your code fails because of `classOf[T]`. `classOf` needs to be given an explicit class, it can't work with a type parameter, even if it has a `ClassTag`.

In the second attempt, you require a `ClassTag` for type `T` but then `createT` requires a `Manifest`. `Manifest` is a subtype of `ClassTag`, and the `ClassTag` that is available cannot safely be downcast to `Manifest`. You are close though, change the requirement to `[T <: AbstractActor : Manifest]` and your code should work.

Comment: Given that Manifest is apparently disappearing at some point in the future, see any pitfalls in replacing it with ClassTag? So we'd have `(implicit tag: ClassTag[T])` and then `Props(tag.runtimeClass, dest)` instead

Comment: It looks like moving to `ClassTag` is the right choice.